# Validating two names in a single name input

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a problem of a single input that has to have two names of a person input. Validating the name input to be of letters worked okay like it is shown here:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $_POST['name'] )){
  echo 'name must be letters';
}
```

That will only validate a single name eg: **John**. But what I need is to validate the that the string contains two words. Like **James Doe**

This is the form input:

```
<input autofocus id="aum" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" type="text" />
```

Comment: Do you want to only allow exactly two words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z'-]+ [a-zA-Z'-]+$
```

Keep in mind, that you are disallowing every other character (e.g. foreign languages). Therefore it is better to use any possible word character. For PHP this would be `\p{L}`

```
^\p{L}+ \p{L}+$
```

You can also use multiple spaces (`^\p{L}+ +\p{L}+$`) or multiple spaces of any type of whitespace:

```
^\p{L}+\s+\p{L}+$
```

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/aUkUKa/2

Comment: good elaboration and my problem is solved in a more advanced way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the meta-character `\s` which match any whitespace character

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$

^\w+\s\w+$
```

Comment: my friend your answer is also okay. Thanks